# In a single chain get a max date - n years

Tags: r, lubridate

(Better title wording recommendations welcome)

```
pacman::p_load(tidyverse, fable, fpp3, feasts)
aus_livestock$Month |> max() |> as_date()
[1] "2018-12-01"
```

I want to get this date minus 6 years in one line. Tried:

```
aus_livestock$Month |> max() |> as_date() |> -years(6)
Error: function '-' not supported in RHS call of a pipe
```

Then tried curly braces `{}`:

```
aus_livestock$Month |> max() |> as_date() |> {. -years(6)}
Error: function '{' not supported in RHS call of a pipe
```

This does work:

```
x <- aus_livestock$Month |> max() |> as_date()
x - years(6)
[1] "2012-12-01"
```

But this involves saving an intermediary variable x. I'd prefer to do it in a oner if there's a way?

Comment: Ha, whoa, just completely missed the news about the new base pipe operator and was wondering what the hell I was looking at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use a lambda function

```
aus_livestock$Month |>
    max() |> 
    as_date() |> 
    (\(x) x - years(6))()
[1] "2012-12-01"
```

Comment: This is new syntax for me! Where does this come from? Is this 'new' or base r or from a package?

Comment: Of course I could look it up, but specifically what does `(\(x)...` do?

Comment: @DougFir It is from the `base R` only.  From `R 4.0` in addition to `|>`, the function(x) is also compacted with `\(x)` it is similar to `(function(x) x - years(6))()` which is a lambda function i..e function created on the fly without assigning it to a new name

Comment: @DougFir you can find some similar examples in `?pipeOp`

Comment: @DougFir It is similar to doing `f1 <-function(x) x - years(6)` and then in the pipe you do `... as_date()|> f1()`